# getting string from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have following static class for localize strings inside my mvc app.
My resource strings are stored inside folder like

- Resources/EnglishStrings.resx
- Resources/DeutschStrings.resx

```
 public static string ReadResourceValue(string lang, string key)
    {
        string file = "";
        if (lang == "en")
        {
            file = "LocalizedUIStrings.en-EN.resx";
        }
        else if (lang == "de")
        {
            file = "LocalizedUIStrings.de-DE.resx";
        }

        //value for our return value
        string resourceValue = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            // specify your resource file name 
            string resourceFile = file;
            // get the path of your file
            //string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            string filePath = @"~/Resources/";
            // create a resource manager for reading from
            //the resx file
            ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
            // retrieve the value of the specified key
            resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            resourceValue = string.Empty;
        }
        return resourceValue;
    }
}
```

this way `string filePath = @"~/Resources/";` I cannot access my folder with resource strings, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server.MapPath` to map virtual path to the physical one.
See [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Resources/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var projectPath =  Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
string filePath = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Resources");
```

or

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"), "Resources");
```